# Determine the image of the unit circle by this transformation.

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute $u$ and $v$ ($z=x+iy$, $w = u + iv$) if $w=\frac{2z-1}{2-z}$. 
Determine the image of the unit circle by this transformation.

I succeed to to the first part of the question. I obtained : $$u(x,y) = \frac{-2x^2-y^2+5x-2}{-4(x-1)+x^2+y^2}$$ $$v(x,y) = \frac{(x+1)y}{-4(x-1)+x^2+y^2}$$

I know I can use the structure $x^2+y^2=1$ or $z=\cos(t)+i \sin(t)$ to get what we want. The problem is I don't know how to handle $u$ and $v$ in such a way we obtain a curve in the complex plane (i.e. $u^2+v^2=a^2$, $u-v^2=b$, $\frac{u}{(v-1)^2}=1$, etc.).

**(*)** $$w=\frac{2z-1}{2-z}$$ $$\iff (2-z)w=(2z-1)$$ $$\iff z= \frac{(2w+1)}{2+w}$$ $$\iff 1=|z|= \frac{|(2w+1)|}{|2+w|}$$ $$\iff  2|(w+½)|=|w+2|$$

Does anyone could give me a hint to complete this question? Is that the part **(*)** can be useful if  I find two polar opposite points on the circle?

Comment: Do you know that Möbius transformations map circles/lines to circles/lines, and preserve angles?

Comment: @MartinR I was just watching it on Wikipedia. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where you left off, $$|2w+1|=|2+w|$$

Now write $$w=u+iv$$ and simplify the expression by writing down the modulus and squaring both sides. You end up with $$u^2+v^2=1$$ which is also the unit circle in the $w-$plane

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Möbius maps take generalised circles (that is, circles or lines) to generalised circles. A generalised circle is precisely determined by three points on it.

More concretely, the map is the same as doing:

$$z \overset{x-2}{\mapsto} z-2 \overset{x^{-1}}{\mapsto} \dfrac{1}{z-2} \overset{-3x}{\mapsto} \dfrac{-3}{z-2} \overset{x-2}{\mapsto} \dfrac{2z-1}{2-z}$$

Each of those maps clearly preserves generalised circles: the first map translates, the second map inverts, the third map scales, and the fourth map translates again. All of those operations preserve generalised circles (that's easy to see, with the possible exception of inversion; there are pretty visualisations of this if you look up the Riemann sphere).

Comment: According to the Möbius transformation, $w$ transforms a circle to another circle. To show this, do I inverse $w$?

Comment: @J.G. What do you mean? A proof that Möbius maps take g. circles to g. circles is given on the Wikipedia page: any Möbius map can be made as a composition of four simpler maps, all of which preserve g. circles.

Comment: I don't know how to use that information. Let me add something on the page shortly. Could you just tell me if I'm well advanced?

Comment: By the way, you don't have to accept an answer if it doesn't answer your question! It looks like my answer didn't help very much.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This is very instructive, but I prefer the way I use.